# Error: Creating a navigator doesn't take an argument REACT NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to upgrade my react-navigation to version 5 and now end up with this error. I have followed the instructions but still having this issue: my Route.js file is

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationNativeContainer from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Drawer } from './Drawer';
import ItemDetailsScreen from '../screens/ItemDetailsScreen';
import ItemSearchScreen from '../screens/ItemSearchScreen';
import ProductScreen from '../screens/ProductScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import CheckoutScreen from '../screens/CheckoutScreen';
import ForgotPasswordScreen from '../screens/ForgotPasswordScreen';
import QRCodeScanner from '../screens/QRCodeScanner';
import BkashScreen from '../screens/BkashScreen';
import CompleteScreen from '../screens/CompleteScreen';
import ScanScreen from '../screens/ScanScreen';
import InitialScreen from '../screens/InitialScreen';
import LogoutScreen from '../screens/LogoutScreen';


const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationNativeContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='InitialScreen'>
        <Stack.Screen name='Drawer' component={Drawer} />
        <Stack.Screen name='LoginScreen' component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='LogoutScreen' component={LogoutScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='QRCodeScanner' component={QRCodeScanner} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ForgotPasswordScreen' component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ItemDetailsScreen' component={ItemDetailsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='CheckoutScreen' component={CheckoutScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='BkashScreen' component={BkashScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='CompleteScreen' component={CompleteScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ScanScreen' component={ScanScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='InitialScreen' component={InitialScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationNativeContainer>
  )
}
```

and Index.js file is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Text, Drawer } from 'native-base';
import App from './config/Routes';
import AppHeader from './components/Header/Header';

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        const { globalContainer } = styles;
        return (
            <App></App>
        )
    }
}
```

Any clue what wrong I have made??

Answer (score 1):

change

```
import NavigationNativeContainer from '@react-navigation/native';
```

to

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Hope this helps!